# Couldn't navigate from one page to another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am new to angularjs...i am trying to navigate from login page to next page using router functionality....My login page is as follows

```
 <body>
<div id='content' ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='LoginController'>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" role="form" ng-submit="login()">
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Login Form</h3>
    <span><b>Username :</b>&nbsp;
        <input type="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"  required>
    </span>
    </br></br>
    <span><b>Password :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required>
    </span>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" >           
     <b>Sign in</b></button>
   {{nameis}}
   </form>
   </div> <!-- /container -->
   </div>
  <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
```

my app.js file is as follows

```
'use strict';
//Define Routing for app

var applog = angular.module('myApp',[]);
applog.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
 function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: '/navAng.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  })    
  .otherwise({
   redirectTo: '/navAng.html'
  });
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //Remove the '#' from URL.
}]);
```

and my controller js file is as follows

```
 applog.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $location,$window){
 $scope.nameis = "Test";

 $scope.go = function ( path ) {
  $location.path( path );
};


$scope.login=function()
   {

    var username=$scope.user.name;
    var password=$scope.user.password;
    if(username=="admin" && password=="admin")
    {

        $location.path( "/navAng.html" );
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.message="Error";
        $scope.messagecolor="alert alert-danger";
    }
  }

});
```

Honestly i dont know where i am going wrong...the problem is i am getting the url of the page correctly in the url tab but i need to press enter to go to that page...i mean the page is not getting refreshed it just changes the existing url and just sits in the same page(i.e login page)....can someone plz help....

Comment: Its present in the same folder where login.html is

Comment: there's no need for `ng-controller='LoginController'` in your markup since you're using routing.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand if you don't specify your controller in your route you have to do it in your view. I guess it's personal preference. To be honest I also declare my controllers in my views. 

To the topicstarter: did you add ngRoute as a dependency?

Comment: @DieterGoetelen Yep you're right, looking at that code it seems that the OP forgot to include the `ngRoute` dependency.

Comment: i have added ngRoute but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add angular-route library too.In latest angular versions, it is available as a separate module.So, you need to inject 'ngRoute' for using $routeProvider service

**index.html:**

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
 <head> 
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';
    //Define Routing for app
    var applog = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    applog.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
         templateUrl: '/login.html',
         controller: 'LoginController'
        })
       .when('/navAng', {
         templateUrl: '/navAng.html',
         controller: 'navAngController'
        })
        .otherwise({
         redirectTo: '/'
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //Remove the '#' from URL.
     }]);

     applog.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $location, $window) {
     //$scope.nameis = "Test";

     $scope.go = function(path) {
       $location.path(path);
     };

    $scope.login = function() {
      var username = $scope.user.name;
      var password = $scope.user.password;
      if (username == "admin" && password == "admin") {
       $location.path("/navAng");
      } else {
       $scope.message = "Error";
       $scope.messagecolor = "alert alert-danger";
      }
    }
  });

  // next page controller
   applog.controller("navAngController", function($scope, $location, $window) {
    $scope.msg= "Success";     
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Use separate html for login. Because, you are using ng-view in index.html
**Login.html:**

```
<div id='content' ng-controller='LoginController'>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-signin" role="form" ng-submit="login()">
  <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Login Form</h3>
  <span><b>Username :</b>&nbsp;
      <input type="username" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"  required>
  </span>      
  <span><b>Password :</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required>
  </span>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
  </label>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  type="submit" >           
   <b>Sign in</b>
  </button>
  {{nameis}}
</form>
</div> <!-- /container -->
</div>
```

This is another page to navigate, when login and password is correct
**navAng.html:**

```
<div> {{msg}} </div>
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your help but still getting the same error even after adding ng-route

Comment: I mean it just doesnt navigate to the next page...it just sits in the same login page